# Get Values from a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a Database query returning objects as a list like this

`table_query_response`:

```
{
   "Items":[
      {
         "groupId":"6501e5ac-59b2-4d05-810a-ee63d2f4f826"
      },
      {
         "groupId":"6501e5ac-59b2-4d05-810a-ee63d2sfdgd"
      }
   ],
   "Count":2,
   "ScannedCount":2,
   "ResponseMetadata":{
      "RequestId":"UEIQVN6HFB9K9Q20IE6J8L48CRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
      "HTTPStatusCode":200,
      "HTTPHeaders":{
         "server":"Server",
         "date":"Thu, 10 Mar 2022 13:42:17 GMT",
         "content-type":"application/x-amz-json-1.0",
         "content-length":"151",
         "connection":"keep-alive",
         "x-amzn-requestid":"UEIQVN6HFB9K9Q20IE6J8L48CRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
         "x-amz-crc32":"2870685196"
      },
      "RetryAttempts":0
   }
}
```

and a different query to just get the specific items

`group_query`:

```
[
   {
      "groupId":"6501e5ac-59b2-4d05-810a-ee63d2f4f826"
   },
   {
      "groupId":"6501e5ac-59b2-4d05-810a-ee63d2sfdgd"
   }
]
```

I want to get a list with values for the key `groupid` and store it like `(6501e5ac-59b2-4d05-810a-ee63d2f4f826, 6501e5ac-59b2-4d05-810a-ee63d2sfdgd)`.

There can be more than two entries in that group query so I will need to get all the values for the `groupid`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What was the problem with using the usual ways to access items in dictionaries and lists?

Comment: I downvote because [there is no attempt shown](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can select the values as GroupID = group_query[0]['groupid'] but that just gets me the 1st value and to get the next one I need to update the index value. My query could have multiple groupid's and I need to store all of those values as a list.

Comment: @Alok do you know how to use loops?

Comment: I need to extract the value for all of the groupid's from my query output above and store it as a list.

Comment: @Alok but do you know how to use loops..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[x['groupId'] for x in table_query_response['Items']]
```